# What is the difference between rx.Observable onErrorResumeNext and onExceptionResumeNext

Tags: java, rx-java

What is the difference between `rx.Observable.onErrorResumeNext` and `rx.Observable.onExceptionResumeNext`?

As far as I understand:

`onErrorResumeNext` triggered by `Throwable`.

`onExceptionResumeNext` triggered by `Exception` only.

Any other details I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation of [`onExceptionResumeNext()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorresumenext):

> Instructs a reactive type to continue emitting items after it encounters an `java.lang.Exception`. Unlike `onErrorResumeNext`, this one lets other types of `Throwable` continue through.

So `onExceptionResumeNext()` only "catches" exceptions, the `onErrorResumeNext()` will "catch" any `Throwable` instances.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I was confused with the name `onErrorResumeNext`. I believe it would be better to use `onThrowableResumeNext` instead, but realize that now it's impossible because of backward compatibility

Comment: The `OnError` might come from the general concept of RX, where the terms `next`, `error` and `complete` are used.